# will this work MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I have a analog clock and a digital clock display. However, I would like to use the MVVM pattern. I don't know where to begin. How to accomplish this? Converting what I have into a pattern shouldn't be so difficult, should it? Would I need a model class and a view class?

I want to keep this as simple as possible. I am sure that once I get the pattern in I won't need two timers?

This is what I have so far. I currently have 2 timers one for digital and one for analog. This I know is bad and with the pattern I won't need it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); //analog clock
    DispatcherTimer timerdigital;                              // digital clock

    public MainWindow() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //analog clock
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Enabled = true;

        //digital clock
        timerdigital = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerdigital.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
        timerdigital.Start();
        timerdigital.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
        {
            tbDigital.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        });
    }

    //analog clock
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            secondHand.Angle = DateTime.Now.Second * 6;
            minuteHand.Angle = DateTime.Now.Minute * 6; 
            hourHand.Angle = (DateTime.Now.Hour * 30) + (DateTime.Now.Minute * 0.5); 
        }));
    }
```

For the xaml code, I drew the hands like this

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF21313" Margin="85,28,86,0" Name="rectangleSecond" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
            <RotateTransform x:Name="secondHand" Angle="0" />
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Fill="#FF181818" Margin="85,27,85,88" Name="rectangleMinute" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
            <RotateTransform x:Name="minuteHand" Angle="0" />
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Fill="#FF070707" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,46,0,89" Name="rectangleHour" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" Width="5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
            <RotateTransform x:Name="hourHand" Angle="0" />
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

I am willing to do this different if I have to.

Comment: I've seen clocks implemented without any code at all.  Can't find a link right now, but it just uses animation and RotateTransforms to move the hands.  Its pretty simple to do.  Same thing could probably be done to animate the visibility of parts of a digital clock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using two different timers, it could be done with the same one.

All you have to do is put your code in a ViewModel, and bind your view to the properties of the ViewModel.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public ClockViewModel()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DigitalTime = now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        SecondAngle = now.Second * 6;
        MinuteAngle = now.Minute * 6; 
        HourAngle = (now.Hour * 30) + (now.Minute * 0.5);
    }

    private string _digitalTime;
    public string DigitalTime
    {
        get { return _digitalTime;}
        set
        {
            _digitalTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DigitalTime");
        }
    }


    private double _hourAngle;
    public double HourAngle
    {
        get { return _hourAngle;}
        set
        {
            _hourAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HourAngle");
        }
    }


    private double _minuteAngle;
    public double MinuteAngle
    {
        get { return _minuteAngle;}
        set
        {
            _minuteAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MinuteAngle");
        }
    }

    private double _secondAngle;
    public double SecondAngle
    {
        get { return _secondAngle;}
        set
        {
            _secondAngle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SecondAngle");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF21313" Margin="85,28,86,0" Name="rectangleSecond" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding SecondAngle}" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Fill="#FF181818" Margin="85,27,85,88" Name="rectangleMinute" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding MinuteAngle}" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Fill="#FF070707" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,46,0,89" Name="rectangleHour" Opacity="0.8" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Stroke="#FFDCDCDC" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="1" Width="5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding HourAngle}" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

(I removed the `TransformGroups` since only the `RotateTransforms` were used)

In the code-behind, just assign an instance of `ClockViewModel` to the `DataContext`.

Comment: I mean in the constructor of your view (Window or UserControl). See the documentation about [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx)

Comment: thank you.. i did lot of research, and followed some tutorials i got the second hand to work. I am coming from a C++ background trying to learn C# and WPF

Comment: Might want to make the "Angle" properties be private set. Doesn't really make sense for outside elements to modify the angles since they are functions of the current time